Using steel angle as deck piers
I have a homestead in a mountainous desert environment-exposed limestone bedrock, no frost in the winter. I'd like to build a deck and was considering using 3cm x 3cm steel angle for the piers-drill 40 cm deep holes into the rock, tap in vertical sections of angle, tie them together with level horizontal angle and screw the decking into those.
Would this work? Would it last?

How are you securing the angle iron into the rock?

Just drilling a 40mm diameter hole with a hammer drill and picket pounding the angle iron down until it hits the bottom. Hypotenuse of 3x3 cm is 4.2, just right.

Steel and limestone rock not the best of friends together.  Steel of that size is usually easy to bend, so unless just above the surface, it might bend from the weight.

That's a really small angle to act as a post. (For the colonists, think 1-1/4".) It doesn't provide enough stiffness. I'd have expected you to propose something more like twice the size.

FYI, "angle iron" is a somewhat archaic term. It's steel, not iron, and it's angle stock or angle extrusion.

It'll project about 10-30 cm above the bedrock.

Yep, that's much too tall for that size.

What made you decide against post bases and 4x4 or 6x6 posts? Angles can be fixed by a puddle of hydraulic cement.

You basic question is "Would it work?"  You have you answer in the comments above.

3cm is very small—less than an inch and a quarter.  Unless you have a lot of piers, I don't think this is a great idea.

How about square extrusions, 3cm x 3cm, every 2 meters?
